# Uri is too long , when xml is converted to bytes and then to memory stream and then encoded and passed as string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

This is my Code . Retrieving my xml file from Db and trying to display using an xslt

```
bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];    
byte[] buffer = bytes;
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(buffer.ToArray());
string decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memory.ToArray());
XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(decoded);
XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTrans.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Xsl/CCD.xsl"));
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("some.html", null);
myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I get error Uri is too long , when XpathDocument line gets executed. I need to display my xml file on the browser ,